# FORG0001: Invalid date. Non-numeric component

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I am trying to convert an XML to another format using XSLT. While converting a date from one format to another, I am getting the below validation error.
**FORG0001: Invalid date "22/12/2020 18:16:34". Non-numeric component**

Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ft_tnx_record xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.misys.com/portal/interfaces/xsd/ft.xsd"/>
    <release_dttm>22/12/2020 18:16:34</release_dttm>
</ft_tnx_record>
```

XSLT Template

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/ft_tnx_record">
        <release_dttm>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-date(release_dttm,'[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')"/>
        </release_dttm>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Driver Java Program

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws TransformerException {
        String filePathPrefix = System.getProperty("user.dir") + System.getProperty("file.separator");

        String directImportInputXmlPath = filePathPrefix + "directImportInputXml.xml";
        StreamSource directImportXml = new StreamSource(new File(directImportInputXmlPath));

        String directImportXsltPath = filePathPrefix + "directImportXslt.xslt";
        StreamSource directImportXslt = new StreamSource(new File(directImportXsltPath));

        String directImportOutputXmlPath = filePathPrefix + "directImportOutputXml.xml";
        StreamResult directImportOutputXml = new StreamResult(new File(directImportOutputXmlPath));

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(directImportXslt);
        transformer.transform(directImportXml, directImportOutputXml);
    }
}
```

I am using XSLT version 2.0 and Saxon-8.7

Comment: The current release of Saxon is Saxon 10.5, the latest 9.x release is 9.9. 8.7 is that old that I think it was released before the XSLT 2 specification was finalized. Nevertheless, I hope the XSD date/dateTime format was supported so basically you need to convert your custom date/dateTime format to `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - I changed the jar from Saxon 8.7 to Saxon-HE 10.5. and got -  FORG0001  Invalid dateTime value "22/12/2020T18:16:34" (Non-numeric year component). Then I changed the date to 2020-12-22T22:10:15 and it is working. So, YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss is valid XSLT date-time format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So try `replace(release_dttm, '([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4}) (.+)', '$3-$2-$1T$4')` to convert to the `xs:dateTime` format, and as Michael Kay pointed out, the complete code then needs to cast and use the right `format` function e.g.

```
  <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(xs:dateTime(replace(release_dttm, '([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4}) (.+)', '$3-$2-$1T$4')),'[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')"/>
```

Needs to declare `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` in the XSLT, to be able to use `xs:dateTime` or `xs:date` functions.

Comment: A caveat here, the result of replace() is a string and there is no automatic casting from string to `xs:dateTime`; so you need to wrap this call in an explicit cast `format-dateTime(xs:dateTime(replace(....)))`. Also need to be clear whether we're using `xs:date` or `xs:dateTime`.

Comment: @MichaelKay, you are right, I amended the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`format-date()` expects the first argument to be of type `xs:date`; but if you supply an untyped node, as you are doing here, it will attempt to cast the string value of that node to an `xs:date` value. This cast will fail (with error FORG0001) if the input is not in the standard ISO date format `yyyy-mm-dd`. It's strongly recommended to use international date formats whenever you store dates in XML, because formats like 03/04/2019 are ambiguous. But if you can't change the XML, then you need to convert it manually to `yyyy-mm-dd` format as @MartinHonnen has suggested.